# JPQL joining tables with where clause

Tags: java, sql, jpql

I hve a table with a forign key like so:

```
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="BASE_ID", updatable = false)
    private Base base;
```

Which connects to a Base table using its "id" .. I'm trying to query this with a where clause but i'm running into errors, my query looks like:

```
return getEntityManager()
.createQuery("SELECT a FROM BaseEventLog a join fetch a.base p WHERE p.eventStatus = 'ERROR'",
                        BaseEventLog.class)
                .getResultList();
```

In sql it would look like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM BASE_EVENT_LOG
  JOIN BASE
  ON BASE.ID=BASE_EVENT_LOG.BASE_ID
  WHERE EVENT_STATUS = 'ERROR'
```

Any suggestions on how to create such a query with jpsql ?

Comment: The query looks alright. What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a FROM BaseEventLog a 
  join a.base p 
WHERE p.eventStatus = 'ERROR'
```

No need for the `fetch`; or atleast I have never used it with JPQL. If you want to use the fetch keyword take a look out how to use it here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins